# Setting the CLSComplaint attribute to true shows error with VisualStudio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2022, cls-compliant

I have set the CLSComplaint attribute to true but i am facing an error with the public properties used. The same code works fine with VS10 but only showing error with VS2022.

```
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
```

[Showing error with the Public property and it does not showing error if we change it as internal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97R0w.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019), the feature is deprecated.  It is recommended not to use that approach, but to keep all build settings within the source-controlled workspace, so that builds are reliable across environments.